# Проблема при использовании CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-sqlite, cursoradaper

Начал делать `CursorAdapter` по [этому примеру](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter)

Я думаю, что все правильно, но появилась ошибка:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
>                                                                          at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
>                                                                          at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:168)
>                                                                          at android.widget.CursorAdapter.(CursorAdapter.java:116)
>                                                                          at db.model.ListAdapter.(ListAdapter.java:17)
>                                                                          at com.vitaliy.usedb.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:91)
>                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4244)
>                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17635)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
>                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
>                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5400)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
>                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
>                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)*

Класс для работы с БД, расширяющий SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    private final String LOG = "####MY_DB_LOG####";

    public static final String TABLE = "mytable";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL = "email";

    private String CreateTable = "create table " +TABLE + " ( "
            + COLUMN_ID +" integer primary key autoincrement,"
            +  COLUMN_NAME +" text not null, "
            + COLUMN_EMAIL +" text " + ")";


    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, "myDb.db", null, 1);
        Log.d(LOG, "create database");
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        Log.d(LOG, "create table");

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(CreateTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }
}
```

Класс расширяющий CursorAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public ListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags){
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_data_list, viewGroup, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_list_item);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_list_item);
        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email_list_item);

        int intId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID));
        String strName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME));
        String strEmail = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_EMAIL));

        id.setText(String.valueOf(intId));
        name.setText(strName);
        email.setText(strEmail);
    }
}
```

И применение CursorAdapter в главном активити:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + DBHelper.TABLE ,null);
                ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(MainActivity.this , cursor, 0);
                listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Как базу создаёте и данными наполняете тут надо показать. А разметка тут совсем не при чём.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, добавил колонку _id но в строчке Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select _id, name, email from " + DBHelper.TABLE ,null);  появилась новая ошибка:
main android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: select _id, name, email from mytable

Comment: Возможно, вы не пересоздали БД после добавления колонки. Попробуйте очистить ресурсы приложения.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, очистил - не помогло (

Comment: Ну... А если сам файл базы вытащить и внутренности посмотреть - там всё в порядке будет?..

Comment: Если БД создана, то второй раз метод `onCreate()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper` не выполняется и колонка соответственно не добавилась (`onCreate()` выполняется только один раз при создании БД). Вы можете либо удалить созданную базу с устройства, чтобы база была создана заново, либо [обновить ее](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/79-urok-39-onupgrade-obnovljaem-bd-v-sqlite) через метод `onUpgrade()` класса `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Comment: @pavlofff, удалил...Потом запустил опять и опять та же!! 
Зашел на смартфоне и посмотрел бд....Почему то там  колонка называется "ID" хотя при создании я ее называл "_id"

Comment: Вам нужно разобраться, почему так происходит. Колонка с автоинкрементом должна называться _id и никак иначе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы получаете сообщение: *column '_id' does not exist* - это значит, что в БД не создана колонка с таким именем (_id), в то время, как она совершенно необходима для работы стандартных классов Android, взаимодействующих с SQLite (В частности класс `Cursor`) и содержит в себе ID записей. (Либо в выборке, предоставленной классу `Cursor` отсутствует эта колонка)

При создании таблицы добавьте создание этой колонки в каждой таблице:

```
CREATE TABLE sometable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, .. )
```

Если есть колонка для ID записей с другим именем - удалите ее.

Если колонка с именем *_id* в БД присутствует, то ее необходимо включить в выборку из БД

Comment: отредактировал свой вопрос!! 
Я создал такую колонку, но ошибка не пропала (

Comment: ошибка изменилась на:
main                                                                  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id (code 1): , while compiling: select _id, name, email from mytable

Comment: причем пишет что ошибка в этой строчке:
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("select  *  from " + DBHelper.TABLE ,null);

Comment: спасибо за отклик, проблему исправил!  Использовал интерфейс BaseColumns и с помощью него создал называние колонки _id!